# How to fix redefined fields from protocol buffer definition in Go?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-go

I'm building a gRPC client using the provider's .proto file and has a couple of enumerations that contains valued with the same name on it.

```
syntax = "proto3";

enum Color {
  NONE = 0;
  BLUE = 1;
}

enum Style {
  SOLID = 0;
  NONE = 1;
}
```

So when I generate the Go service for the .proto file and try and run it, I get the following error:

```
...\deal.pb.go:460:2: NONE redeclared in this block
...\deal.pb.go:105:2: other declaration of NONE
```

I tried moving the enumerations inside messages, like Color inside Shape, and expected this to provide a different name space. but did not work. Generated code declares blocks of constants and the message does not provide name spacing as I was hoping for. This worked for C#.

```
const (
  NONE Shape = 0
  BLUE Shape = 1
)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rename the enum values because the primary problem in the provided code is that the generated Go code contains two constants with the name **NONE**, one from the **Color** enum and one from the **Style** enum. This causes a naming conflict because, in go, all constants from the generated protobuf code exist at the package level, making them global to the package.
So, may be you can try this:

```
enum Color {
  COLOR_NONE = 0;
  COLOR_BLUE = 1;
}

enum Style {
  STYLE_SOLID = 0;
  STYLE_NONE = 1;
}
```